# Terminal won't accept commands

Tags: mac, terminal

I can't enter any commands into my terminal. If I type something in and hit enter it just moves to the next line but noting happens. This message also shows up after like 10 seconds everytime I open terminal.

```
-bash(16772,0x7fffe4e2a3c0) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744072117301248) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
-bash: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744072117299336 bytes

[Process completed]
```

Comment: You could always upgrade your machine to 18 exabytes of RAM, so the memory allocation (`malloc`) won't fail :) Seems like there is a bug in your `bash` somehow. Try changing your shell to something else and see if that avoids the problem. Then you can manually start `bash` and try to recreate the problem.

Comment: Does the problem persist across reboots?

Comment: This might also be caused by something in one of the bash init files in your home folder (any of .bashrc, .bash_profile, .bash_login, and .profile). Note that these files' names start with ".", and hence are usually invisible. You can look for them in TextEdit, by getting an Open dialog (Command-O), navigating to your home folder (Command-Shift-H), then switching on show invisibles mode (Command-Shift-Period). You can also open the files in TextEdit to view their contents, but be careful about making changes -- TextEdit sometimes uses characters that doesn't work in shell scripts.

Comment: @spiff yes it does

Comment: @GordonDavisson Those files are huge, how would I know if something is wrong in them?

Comment: @TylerBloom Very hard to tell in general. Those are scripts that get run by new shells as they start up, to get the shell's environment and configuration properly set up. What belongs in them... depends completely on what custom setup you have. If they're huge and you're not familiar with their content, that probably means that software you've installed/used has added customization/setup/whatever instructions to them, and something has gone wrong with at least one of the customizations. Option 1: add the files' contents to your question (use code format) and maybe some'll spot a problem.

Comment: Option 2: add the command `set -x` to the beginning of .bash_profile, .bash_login, or .profile (whichever is the first on that list that exists); this'll make the shell print out commands as it executes them, so you can see what command is making it die. But I still recommend against using TextEdit to make changes; I recommend [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) instead. It works great for editing scripts, and you can use it for free in demo mode.

Comment: .bashrc, .bash_login, and .profile don't seem to be anywhere in my files. .bash_profile is thousands of lines of code should I just copy paste it all in the post?

Comment: I also cannot access .bash_profile from BBEdit or TextEdit

Comment: Ok I found some other things online and now I can open the .bash_profile file in Text Edit. This line is repeating thousands of times which might be part of the problem- 
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:‚Äô/usr/local/bin:Äô:/Users/tyler1313/Applications/Visual:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"

Comment: I just deleted all of those lines and now my terminal is working again. I think the problem was just the size of .bash_profile